# Unmet depencies after messing around with gcc symbolic links

Tags: 13.04, gcc

I'm a linux noob and I messed up symbolic links on Ubuntu 13 for my gcc 4.7 which should be installed but I can't remove it nor use it:

```
paul@paul-linux:~$ sudo apt-get remove gcc-4.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dkms : Depends: gcc but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.


paul@paul-linux:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/gcc
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this please?

Comment: What's the output of sudo apt-get install gcc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will fix your problem but try the commands below it may fix your problem. After running these commands try to install gcc again.

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get -f install